# Javascript php form validation issue

Tags: javascript, php, css, forms, validation

So here is my problem. if you follow the pictures. simple form. click on name. name moves up underline pulls across. you fill out name then go to next. It gives a nice background with checkmark. validation works great, but problem is with picture 5. after form is checked with php it comes back as errors which is great, but the blue background is gone and the text is behind the name placeholder. Does anyone have a solution to why this is happening?

resting
[image]
when clicked
[image]
when filled
[image]
when completed
[image]
error and name is hidden until clicked
[image]
clicked
[image]

The problem I am having is if the fill something out and forget to fill out a required field. The input they filled out is still there but hidden. You can see it if you click the field, but I would like it to stay like when you first fill it out. I know this may sound confusing thats why i am putting the code here. I hope someone out there could teach me some knowledge!

form.

```
<?php include('validate.php');?>

            <?php include('header.php') ?>

              <form id="contact_form" class="contact_form" action="contact.php" 
    id="contact_form" method="post">

                   <h2>Have a Question?</h2>

                  <div class="textinput <?php echo $nameErr ?>">
                        <?php
                            if(!empty($nameErr))
                            {
                        ?>
                      <div class="requiredline">
                      </div>
                      <?php
                            }
                        ?>
                <div class="textinput ">
              <input name="Name" type="text" id="Name" 
placeholder="First & Last" 
value="<?php echo (isset($Name) ? $Name : ""); ?>" />
              <label for="Name">Name</label><div class="labelunderline"></div>
                  </div><span class='text_error'><?php echo $nameErr;?></span>



                      <div class="textinput <?php echo $nameErr ?>">
                        <?php
                            if(!empty($nameErr))
                            {
                        ?>
                      <div class="requiredline">
                      </div>
                      <?php
                            }
                        ?>
                  <div class="textinput">
              <input name="Email" type="text" id="Email" 
        placeholder="Email@mail.com" value="<?php echo (isset($Email) ? $Email : ""); ?>" />
              <label for="Email">Email</label>
        <div class="labelunderline"></div><!--END LABEL UNDERLINE-->
                  </div><span class='text_error'><?php echo $emailErr;?></span>

                  <div class="textinput ">
              <input type="text" id="Message" placeholder="Write what you feel" />
              <label for="Message">Message</label><div class="labelunderline"></div>
                  </div>

                <div class="input-wrap">
                  <button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT"
     class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6">Submit</button>
                </div>

              </form><!--END FORM-->

            <?php include('footer.php') ?>
```

footer that holds the javascript for when option is filled.

```
 <script>

    $(".textinput input").change(function() {
      if ($(this).val() != "") {
        $(this).addClass('filled');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('filled');
      }
    })

    </script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

css

```
 body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        }



        /*============CONTACT PAGE=====================*/

        #contact_header_text {
            width: 100%;
            height: 55vh;
            padding-top: 135px;
            font-family: Raleway-reg;
            font-size: 2.5em;
            color: white;
            background-image: 
    linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 79, 88, 0.5),
 100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)), url("../images/IMG_1464.jpg");
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: top center;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
            background-color: #dbdbdb;
        }

        #contact_section {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 1.5em;
            color: #333;
            font-family: Raleway-reg;
            background-color: #fff;  
        }

        #contact_form {
            max-width: 1200px;
            margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
            padding-top: 35px;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
          text-align: right;
          font-family: Raleway-reg;
          font-style: italic;
            font-weight: bold;
          color: #096771;
          font-size: 15px;
        }

        ::-moz-placeholder {
          text-align: right;
          font-family: Raleway-reg;
          font-style: italic;
            font-weight: bold;
          color: #096771;
          font-size: 15px;
        }

        button {
          background: #3eacb8;
          border: none;
          border-radius: 2px;
          color: #fff;
          padding: 25px;
          font-size: 14px;
          font-weight: bold;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          text-align: center;
          vertical-align: middle;
          font-family: Raleway-med;
          margin-bottom: 30px;
          letter-spacing: 3px;

        }

        button:hover {
            background-color: #096771;
            transition: 0.5s all;
            text-decoration: none;
            letter-spacing: 6px;
        }


        label {
          top: 10px;
          position:absolute;
          left: 35px;
          transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
        }

        .textinput {
          height: 3em;
          margin: 1em 0;
          position: relative;
          width: 100%;
        }

        .textinput input,
        .textinput label {
          cursor: pointer;
          font-size: 1.25em;
          font-family: Raleway-reg;
          text-align: left;
          padding: 0.6em 1% 0.15em 1%;
          /*
          position: absolute;
          */
          transition: all 0.15s ease;
          width: 100%;
        }

        .labelunderline {
          height: 1px;
          width: 100%;
          background-color: #3eacb8;
          position: absolute;
          bottom: 3px;
          left: 0;
        }

        .textinput input {
           text-decoration: none;
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
            border-left: none;
            border-top: none;
            border-right: none;
            width: 0%;
            float: left;
            transition: 0.5s ease;
            white-space: nowrap;   
        }

        .textinput input:focus {
            border-bottom: 3px solid #096771;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .textinput input.filled {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .textinput label {
          color: #3eacb8;
          padding: 0.6em 0;
          margin-left: -1em;
        }

        .textinput input.filled ~ label,
        .textinput input:focus ~ label {
          font-size: 0.6em;
          font-weight: 600;
          margin-top: -15px;
          position: absolute;
        }

        .textinput input.filled ~ label {
          color: #096771;
        }

        .textinput input[type="text"].filled,
        .textinput input[type="email"].filled:valid {
          background: #3eacb8;
          color: white;
          opacity: 0.4;
        }

        /*=================CHECKMARK========================*/
        .textinput input[type="text"].filled ~label:after,
        .textinput input[type="email"].filled:valid ~label:after {
          color: #096771;
          content: "\f058";
          display: inline-block;
          font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
          font-size: 3em;
          text-rendering: auto;
          -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
          -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
          position: absolute;
          top: 15px;
          right: 35px;
          transform: translate(0, 0);
        }


        .error {
            /*
            text-align: left;
            margin-top: 5px;
            */
            color: #FF0000;
            font-family: pathwaygothic;
            /*
            display: block;
            background-image:url(../images/x.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: left;
            padding-left: 30px;
            */
        }

        .text_error {
            text-align: left;
            margin-top: -15px;
            color: #FF0000;
            display: block;
            font-family: pathwaygothic;
            background-image:url(../images/x.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: left;
            padding-left: 30px;
        }

        div.error {
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 19px;
            margin-top: 5px;
            background-image:url(../images/x.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: left;
            padding-left: 30px; 
            margin-left: 25px;
        }

        .requiredline {
            height: 4px;
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px;
            left: 0;
            background-color: red;
        }
```

and lastly the validate form

```
<?php
        session_start();
            // define variables and set to empty values
            $nameErr = $emailErr = $phoneErr = $describeErr = $humanErr = $subjectmatterErr = "";
            $Name = $Email = $Phone = $Describe = $Human = 
$Subjectmatter = "";

            $hasError = false;
            $sent = false;

            if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $Name                = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['Name'], ENT_QUOTES));
                $Email               = trim($_POST['Email']);
                $Describe            = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['Describe'], ENT_QUOTES));
                $Phone               = trim($_POST['Phone']);
                $Company             = trim($_POST['Company']);
                $Website             = trim($_POST['Website']);
                $Subjectmatter       = trim($_POST['Subjectmatter']);
                $Human               = trim($_POST['Human']);
                $Number              = 8;        

                $fieldsArray = array(
                    'Name' => $Name,
                    'Email' => $Email,
                    'Describe' => $Describe,
                    'Phone' => $Phone,
                    'subjectmatter' => $Subjectmatter,
                    'Human' => $Human
                );

                $errorArray = array();

                foreach($fieldsArray as $key => $val) {
                    switch ($key) {
                        case 'Name':
                            if(empty($val)) {
                                $hasError = true;
                                $nameErr = "Please enter your name.";
                            }
                        case 'Name':
                            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", ($val))) {
                                $hasError = true;
                                $nameErr = "The value must be alphanumeric."; 
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'Phone':
                            if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", ($val))) {
                                $hasError = true;
                                $phoneErr = "Only numbers and white space allowed.";
                            }
                        case 'Phone':
                            if(empty($val)) {
                                $hasError = true;
                                $phoneErr = "Phone is required.";
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'Subjectmatter':
                            if(empty($val)) {
                                $hasError = true;
                                $subjectmatterErr = "Subject is required.";
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'Email':
                            if(!filter_var($Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                                $hasError = true;
                                $emailErr = "Email is required.";
                            } else {
                                $Email = filter_var($Email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'Describe' :
                            if (strlen($val) < 25) {
                                $hasError = true;
                                $describeErr = "Please enter at least 25 characters. 
    This way I know more specifically what you need!";
                            }
                        case 'Describe' :
                            if(empty($val)) {
                                $hasError = true;
                                $describeErr = "Message is required. 
    This way I know what you need!";
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'Human':
                            if (!preg_match("/[^\d]?8[^\d]?/", ($val))) {
                                $hasError = true;
                                $humanErr = "Not the right answer";
                            }
                        case 'Human':
                            if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", ($val))) {
                                $hasError = true;
                                $humanErr = "Must be a number";
                            }
                        case 'Human':
                            if(empty($val)) {
                                $hasError = true;
                                $humanErr = "Are you human?";
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }

                //Validation Success!
                //Do form processing like email, database etc here
                if($hasError !== true) {
                    $priority = $_POST['priority'];
                    $type = $_POST['type'];
                    $message = $_POST['message'];

                    $formcontent=" From: $Name \n Company: $Company \n 
    Email: $Email \n Phone: $Phone \n 
    Website: $Website \n Subject: $Subjectmatter 
    \n Describe: $Describe \n\n";
                    $recipient = "email@email.com";
                    $subject = "Contact Form";
                    $mailheader = "From: $Email \r\n";
                    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, 
$mailheader /*$message, $headers*/);
                    header("Refresh:0; url=thanks.php");
                    exit();       
                }
            }

        ?><!--END PHP-->
```

I know someone can figure out where i screwed up!

Comment: i did with my last comment. I dont know how to shrink this down anymore and have it be functional for someone to help me test out the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the blue background comes from the `change` event handler, which adds and removes the class 'filled' to the input, but when you reload the page nobody calls it.

To let things easy I suggest that you refactor your javascript and call it on 
`$(document).ready`.

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function checkInput(elem){
      if ($(elem).val() != "") {
        $(elem).addClass('filled');
      } else {
        $(elem).removeClass('filled');
      }

    }

    $(".textinput input").change(function() {
      checkInput(this);
    });

    $(".textinput input").each(function(){
        checkInput(this);
    });
}
```

Otherwise you can do it in the php side. Then on every input you've to check whether the field has a values with `isset`and add the class to the input.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0dzkotxm/1/)

Comment: just tried it. when if fill info out the background is not even visible anymore

Comment: try now, I made a small change

Comment: how would I add it to the php side. i havent really added classes before

Comment: You may try it in PHP side as Massimo suggested! 

class="<?php echo (isset($Name) ? "filled" : ""); ?>"

Comment: still gives me the same result

Comment: Can you please check whether you got $Name back?

Comment: okay i tried the php route. it shows the blue box, but shows it even before entering in anything

Comment: okay it does keep the name after validate now. just have to get rid of blue box before

Comment: To retain the value of form fields you can set those value in session. And you can use that to fill your form.

Comment: how would you go about doing that?

Comment: are you sure that you posted all the JS in your page ?

Comment: yeah the script for the filled is all that was needed for the form

Comment: there was a typo error in my answer :( Now it seems work. . PS I see you don't always close your divs in your page, see my fiddle

Comment: holy crap! This is working now. at first it only showed the blue background when i submitted something. but I went back in and added the original class filled js to it and now it works perfect. I do now see I missed two </div> now i have to make sure i place those right! Thanks for the help you are the man!!!!

Comment: I'm happy man, I had put all those checkElem calls, while my function was called checkInput so it generated an error ..if you still have checkElem in your code, change it with checkInput